# Grafana build from source with docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile, path setup error, go command not found

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile, grafana

I am trying to install Grafana with docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile. This is giving me error of "go command not found"; I think this is because gopath is not setup properly. Same commands I have run one by one in host machine everything is working but same process I am trying with Docker and it is giving me error.

NOTE for error checking please click on link in last.

My docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
   web:
      build: .
      container_name: grafana
      ports:
        - "9000:3000"
      expose:
        - 9000
      volumes:
        - .:/newvolebs
      networks:
        - overlay
      environment:
         MYSQL_HOST: mysql
         MYSQL_DATABASE: grafana
         MYSQL_USERNAME: root
         MYSQL_PASSWORD: 12345
   mysql:
      image: mysql:5.6
      ports:
        - "3306:3306"
      expose:
        - 3306
      volumes:
        - newvolebs:/var/lib/mysql
      networks:
        - overlay
      environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345
          MYSQL_DATABASE: grafana
volumes:
 newvolebs:
   driver: local
networks:
 overlay:
   driver: "bridge"
```

my DockerFile

```
FROM centos:centos7
RUN     useradd centos && \
        yum install -y sudo && \
        echo "centos ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
USER centos
ENV PATH="/home/centos/go:${PATH}"
RUN     sudo cd /home/centos && \
        sudo yum -y update && \
        sudo yum --setopt=tsflags=nodocs -y install \
        wget \git \
        gcc-c++ make \tar && \
        sudo wget https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.11.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz && \
        sudo tar -xzvf go1.11.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz && \
        sudo mv go gocode && \
        curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo bash && \
        sudo yum -y install nodejs && \
        yum clean all && \
        sudo chmod 666 ~/.bashrc && \
        sudo echo "export GOROOT=$HOME/gocode" >> ~/.bashrc \
        && sudo echo "export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin" >> ~/.bashrc \
        && sudo echo "export GOPATH=$HOME/go" >> ~/.bashrc \
        && sudo echo "export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin" >> ~/.bashrc && \
        PATH="${GOROOT}/bin:$PATH}" && \
        export GOPATH=/home/centos/go && \
        export GOROOT=/home/centos/gocode && \
        source /home/centos/.bashrc && \
        sudo mkdir -p $HOME/go/{src,pkg,bin} && \
        cd $GOPATH/src && \
        go get github.com/grafana/grafana && \
        cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/grafana/grafana && \
        go run build.go setup \
        go run build.go build && \
        npm install -g yarn && \
        yarn install --pure-lockfile && \
        yarn watch && \
        cd go/src/github.com/grafana/grafana/bin/  && \
        grafana-server \
        echo "[main_settings]" > /var/www/html/config.ini \
        && echo "headerTitle='Dashboard'" >> /var/www/html/config.ini \
        && echo "encryptKey='ffgfjhvjhvjcfgfjj'" >> /var/www/html/config.ini \
        && echo ";Timezone Setting. ex: 'America/New_York'" >> /var/www/html/config.ini \
        && echo "defaultTimezone=''" >> /var/www/html/config.ini \
        && echo ";Database parameters for system usage (Should not be used by custom dashboard/charts)" >> /var/www/html/config.ini \
        && echo "dashboardDatabaseServer=mysql" >> /var/www/html/config.ini \
        && echo "dashboardDatabaseName=dashboard" >> /var/www/html/config.ini \
        && echo "dashboardDatabaseUserName=root" >> /var/www/html/config.ini \
        && echo "dashboardDatabasePassword=12345 >> /var/www/html/config.ini \
        && echo ";grafana credentials" >> /var/www/html/config.ini \
        && echo "grafanaDatabaseServer=mysql" >> /var/www/html/config.ini \
        && echo "grafanaDatabaseName=grafana" >> /var/www/html/config.ini \
        && echo "grafanaDatabaseUserName=root" >> /var/www/html/config.ini \
        && echo "grafanaDatabasePassword=12345" >> /var/www/html/config.ini && \
EXPOSE  9000
WORKDIR  /home/centos
```

[This is the error when I execute docker-compose build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ8AZ.png)

Comment: can you try `$HOME/gocode/bin/go` instead of `go`.

Comment: you should also look at multi stage build - https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#use-multi-stage-builds

Comment: not working same error

Comment: Why not use an image with go installed?

Comment: i am having different kind of setup thats why i am looking for this way

Comment: Please do not include screen shots of terminal windows; just paste the actual error message that's being produced into your question.

Comment: go command not found is the error message i am getting

Comment: how can i set path in bash rc and make it run

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.